# Does the latest Chrome makes opacity triggers paint?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-transitions, paint, opacity

does anybody know if the latest chrome makes opacity transition triggers paint? I've just realize about it yesterday when I was using slider plugin, I've tested it before, it didn't cause paint since it promote the elements to new layers with transform: translateZ. But now it seems that it triggers paint. I know about the floating point hack to deal with the opacity, something like this: "opacity: 0.99999" but I've also read that it would cause performance issue. Does anybody could give me some solutions. Appreciate it. Here's my code:

```js
window.app = window.app || {};

app.slider = function (setting) {
 'use strict';
 
 var idWrapper = document.getElementById(setting.wrapperID),
  idSlider = document.getElementById(setting.sliderID),
  sliderChilds = idSlider.children,
  totalChilds = sliderChilds.length,
  index = 0,
  start,
  _play,
  _stop;
 
 if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
  var autoPlay = true;
  var delay = setting.delay || 5000;
  
  _play = function () {
   start = setInterval(_next, delay);
  }

  _stop = function () {
   clearInterval(start);
  }
 }
 
 if (!!setting.pagingID) {
  var idPaging = document.getElementById(setting.pagingID),
   pagingChilds = idPaging.children;
 }

 if (!!setting.navButton) {
  var buttonNext = function() {
   var divNext = document.createElement('div');
   divNext.classList.add('nav-slider');
   divNext.classList.add('next');
   idWrapper.appendChild(divNext);
   divNext.addEventListener('click', _next, false);
   if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
    divNext.addEventListener('mouseenter', _stop, false);
    divNext.addEventListener('mouseleave', _play, false);
   }
  };

  var buttonPrev = function() {
   var divPrev = document.createElement('div');
   divPrev.classList.add('nav-slider');
   divPrev.classList.add('prev');
   idWrapper.appendChild(divPrev);
   divPrev.addEventListener('click', _prev, false);
   if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
    divPrev.addEventListener('mouseenter', _stop, false);
    divPrev.addEventListener('mouseleave', _play, false);
   }
  };
 }

 function _changeSlide(index1, index2) {
  requestAnimationFrame(function () {
   sliderChilds[index1].classList.remove('active');
   sliderChilds[index2].classList.add('active');
   if (!!setting.pagingID) {
    pagingChilds[index1].classList.remove('active');
    pagingChilds[index2].classList.add('active');
   }
   if (!!setting.external) {
    setting.external();
   }
  });
 }

 function _next() {
  if (index < totalChilds - 1) {
   _changeSlide(index, index + 1);
   index++;
  } else {
   _changeSlide(index, 0);
   index = 0;
  }
 }

 function _prev() {
  if (index > 0) {
   _changeSlide(index, index - 1);
   index--;
  } else {
   _changeSlide(index, totalChilds - 1);
   index = totalChilds - 1;
  }
 }
 
 function _setSlider() {
  idWrapper.classList.add('slider-wrapper');
  sliderChilds[0].classList.add('active');
  if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
   _play();
  }
  if (!!setting.navButton) {
   buttonNext();
   buttonPrev();
  }
  if (!!setting.pagingID) {
   pagingChilds[0].classList.add('active');
   for (var i = 0; i < totalChilds; i++) {
    (function (indexPaging) {
     if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
      pagingChilds[indexPaging].addEventListener('mouseenter', _stop, false);
      pagingChilds[indexPaging].addEventListener('mouseleave', _play, false);
     }
     pagingChilds[indexPaging].addEventListener('click', function () {
      if (indexPaging !== index) {
       _changeSlide(index, indexPaging);
       index = indexPaging;
      }
     }, false);
    })(i);
   }
  }
 }

 _setSlider();

 if (!!setting.autoPlay) {
  var publicAPI = {};

  publicAPI.play = _play;
  publicAPI.stop = _stop;
  
  return publicAPI;
 } else {
  return 'no autoplay';
 }
};

 window.onload = function () {
   'use strict';
   
   // Create all sliders needed
   app.slider1 = app.slider({
    wrapperID : 'slider-wrapper-1',
    sliderID : 'slider1',
    pagingID : 'paging-slider1',
    autoPlay : true,
    navButton : true
   });
  };
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.wrapper {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 0px;
}


/* SLIDER CSS */
.slider-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.slider-content {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
}
.slider-item {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  opacity: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  transform: translateZ(0);
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
.slider-item.active {
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
}
.slider-paging {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
        transform: translateZ(0);
}
.paging-item {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.paging-item.active {
  background-color: black;
}
.nav-slider {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 50%;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: -25px;
        font-size: 0;
        opacity: .5;
        background-color: black;
        transform: translateZ(0);
        transition: opacity 200ms ease-in-out 0ms;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .nav-slider:hover {
        opacity: .75;
    }
    .prev:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 16px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: -7px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    }
    .prev:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        right: 16px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }
    .next:before {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 16px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: -7px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotateZ(45deg);
    }
    .next:after {
        content: '';
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 16px;
        width: 20px;
        height: 3px;
        margin-top: 5px;
        background-color: #fff;
        transform: rotateZ(-45deg);
    }
    .prev {
        left: 0;
    }
    .next {
        right: 0;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Slider</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div id="slider-wrapper-1">
                <div id="slider1" class="slider-content">
                    <div class="slider-item"></div>
                    <div class="slider-item"></div>
                    <div class="slider-item"></div>
                </div>
                <div id="paging-slider1" class="slider-paging">
                    <div class="paging-item"></div>
                    <div class="paging-item"></div>
                    <div class="paging-item"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be able to use [the Performance tab of  Chrome's Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) to identify any instances of paint triggers. I suggest reducing your test considerably before doing so though.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I know which elements trigger paint, what I don't know is why it happens now, since I already promoted elements that will have transition to a new layer using translateZ and I only use opacity and transform properties that are meant to be paintless operation and I know it wasn't causing any paint before since I had already test it.